# Python: download files with authentification using requests or urllib3

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, urllib3

I am prety new with python and I need a little help. At work we have a local server from where I would like to download files. Before downloading you need authentificate yourself.
For downloading I create two scripts. Script with urllib3 is working fine, but the other one, where I use requests doesn't.
Can somebody please check the scripts and tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you.

This one is working

```
import urllib3
url = 'http://q32wad/documents/bills.pdf'
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
headers = urllib3.util.make_headers(basic_auth='username123:password123')
r = http.request('GET', url, headers=headers)
print("STATUS = " + str(r.status))
print("HEADERS = " + str(r.headers))

results:
STATUS = 200
HEADERS = HTTPHeaderDict({'Date': 'Sun, 05 Aug 2018 15:07:32 GMT', 'Server': 'Apache', 'Content-Length': '636', 'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1'})
```

This one is not working

```
import requests
from base64 import b64encode
url = 'http://q32wad/documents/bills.pdf'
# try 1
# r = requests.get(url, auth=('username123', 'password123'))
# r = requests.get(url)
# try 2
# headers = {'username': 'username123', 'password': 'password123'}
# r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
# try 3
# userAndPass = b64encode(b"username123:password123").decode("ascii") 
# headers = { 'authorization' : 'Basic %s' % userAndPass }
# r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
# try 4
c = requests.Session()
c.auth =('username123', 'password123')
r = c.get(url)
print("STATUS " + str(r.status_code))
print("HEADERS " + str(r.headers))
results:
STATUS 502
HEADERS {'Date': 'Sun, 05 Aug 2018 15:11:28 GMT', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset="UTF-8"', 'Content-Length': '2477', 'Accept-Ranges': 'none', 'Proxy-Connection': 'close'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, solution, for my case, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48708857/python-requests-through-vpn-giving-502-bad-gateway) post help me

Final working code is below

```
c = requests.Session()
c.auth =('username123', 'password123')
c.trust_env = False
r = s.get(url)
```

If anybody knows, what is "trust_env = False" for?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this: [Python: request basic auth doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745462/python-request-basic-auth-doesnt-work)

It seems like you're missing a step, actually authenticating with the server.

```
c = requests.Session()
c.auth =('username123', 'password123')
auth = c.post('http://' + url)
r = c.get(url)
```

Comment: Thanks for help, but it doesn't work. And idea? this is what I try c = requests.Session()
c.auth =('username123', 'password123')
auth = c.post(url)
r = c.get(url)

Comment: I try also this example from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth r = requests.get(url, auth=HTTPDigestAuth(username123, 'password123')) Also doesn't work. Where is the trick??

Comment: I'm sorry, this seems to work on my end. I'm not sure how I can help you any further, can you provide some more information?

Comment: @Spiderbo Thank you for sharing your thouhts. It is really frustrating why downloading with urllib3 is working but with requests don't. The same file, same server. It must be some trick. At the end I will have to continue with urllib3, because of time of delivery solution.

Comment: Ok, sorry I couldn't help you any further. Good luck!